# Determining power series $\mathrm{e}^z$ and $\sin^2z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the powerseries of the following functions:

$f(z)=\mathrm{e}^z$ in $a=5$

$f(z)=\sin^2(z)$ in $a=0$.

I don't know if I'm making a mistake, but the first one is a powerseries I already know:
$\mathrm{e}^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}=\frac{z^n}{n!}$, so the only thing to do is replace the $z$ by $z-5$?
And the second one? Can anybody help me with how to work out this exercise?

Comment: I guess that "determine" stands for finding out independently of whether you know it already or not. You know the Taylor series expansion? I guess you have to develop it around the value $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1)

> $$ \sin(z)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2z)). $$

2)

> $$\cos t = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{2k} .$$

3) For the first one you should have

> $$ e^z = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^5}{k!}(z-5)^{k}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$e^z=e^5 e^{z-5}$$

$$\sin^2(z)=(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i})^2=-[\frac{1}{4}e^{2iz}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}e^{-2iz}]$$

Answer (score 0):

You're correct about the first one. To solve the second part one could either: square the power series for $\sin(z)$ explicitly or cleverly exploit a trigonometric identity that expresses $\sin^2(z)$ in terms of twice some other trigonometric function (hint hint). Good luck!